# swift: How to create UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create `UIPageViewController` with spine mid location. I read several tutorials with `UIPageViewController` but in this tutorials  used spine min or max location. And I can not create `UIPageViewController` with spine mid location.

I have this function to create `UIPageViewController` with spine mid location min or max location:

```
func createPageViewController() {

            // Instantiate the PageViewController
            let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
            pageController.dataSource = self
            pageController.delegate = self

            if images.count > 0{
                let contentController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 0)!
                let contentControllers = [contentController]

                pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

            pageViewController = pageController

            self.addChildViewController(pageViewController!)

            self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
            pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        }
```

I tried to change it for this:

```
let contentController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 0)!
let contentController1 = getContentViewController(withIndex: 1)!
let contentControllers = [contentController, contentController1]
```

But in this case my images not showing in pages. It is not help. What am I doing wrong? How to create `UIPageViewController` with spine mid location?

**Update**

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var PageControl: UIPageControl!

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    var images = ["book1page1.png","book1","book1","book1page2.png","book1page1.png","book1page2.png"]
    var pendingIndex: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControll()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createPageViewController() {
        // Instantiate the PageViewController
        let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        pageController.dataSource = self
        pageController.delegate = self

        if images.count > 0{
            let firstController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 0)!
            let contentControllers = [firstController]

            pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        pageViewController = pageController

        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController!)

        //self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
        self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, at: 0)
        pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }

    //Setup Pagination Icons and count
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func setupPageControll(){
        let apperance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        apperance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        apperance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        apperance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func currentControllerIndex() -> Int{
        let pageItemController = self.currentConroller()

        if let controller = pageItemController as? ContentViewController {
            return controller.itemIndex
        }
        return -1
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    func currentConroller() -> UIViewController?{
        if (self.pageViewController?.viewControllers?.count)! > 0{
            return self.pageViewController?.viewControllers![0]
        }

        return nil
    }

    func getContentViewController(withIndex index: Int) -> ContentViewController? {
        if index < images.count{
            let contentVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
            contentVC.itemIndex = index
            contentVC.imageName = images[index]

            return contentVC
        }

        return nil
    }

}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        pendingIndex = (pendingViewControllers.first as! ContentViewController).itemIndex
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed {
            let currentIndex = pendingIndex
            if let index = currentIndex {
                self.PageControl.currentPage = index
            }

        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentViewController
        if contentVC.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex - 1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentViewController
        if contentVC.itemIndex + 1 < images.count {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex + 1)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting its view's frame, pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your PageViewController on story board and set. Spine Location `none` to `Mid`. Also Check `double sided`.

[image]

Modify your code as below. (Changes done on your own code)

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var PageControl: UIPageControl!

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    var images = ["01","02","03","04"]
    var pendingIndex: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControll()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createPageViewController() {
        let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        pageController.isDoubleSided = true
        pageController.dataSource = self
        pageController.delegate = self

        if images.count > 1{
            let firstController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 0)!
            let secondController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 1)!
            let contentControllers = [firstController,secondController]
            pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        pageViewController = pageController
        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
        self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, at: 0)
        pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }

    //Setup Pagination Icons and count
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func setupPageControll(){
        let apperance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        apperance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        apperance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        apperance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func currentControllerIndex() -> Int{
        let pageItemController = self.currentConroller()

        if let controller = pageItemController as? ContentView {
            return controller.itemIndex
        }
        return -1
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    func currentConroller() -> UIViewController?{
        if (self.pageViewController?.viewControllers?.count)! > 0{
            return self.pageViewController?.viewControllers![0]
        }

        return nil
    }

    func getContentViewController(withIndex index: Int) -> ContentView? {
        if index < images.count{
            let contentVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentView
            contentVC.itemIndex = index
            //contentVC.imageName.image = self.images[index]

            return contentVC
        }

        return nil
    }

}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        pendingIndex = (pendingViewControllers.first as! ContentView).itemIndex
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentView

        if contentVC.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex - 1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentView
        if contentVC.itemIndex + 1 < images.count {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex + 1)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

[Github Full Project](https://github.com/pranavansp/Double-Sided-Page-UIPageViewController-Swift).

Comment: I get error: `The number of provided view controllers (1) doesn't match the number required (2) for the requested spine location (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid)`

Comment: @111 Can you post all of your code related to this? are you doing like book paging.

Comment: Updated question. I doing like real book with flipping pages. https://previews.123rf.com/images/victoroancea/victoroancea1007/victoroancea100700013/7292811-front-view-of-open-book-on-white-background.jpg

Comment: @111 Your code does give any error its worked after removed ```func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating```. Are you setting image correctly in ```ContentViewController```

Comment: After removed `func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating` my code have same error. I added all code in the question and you can see how I setting image.

Comment: Do you have any ideas to solve the problem? How can I create a second controller??

Comment: @111 Confirm me. you going to show only one page at the time or two. Your code working perfect to show only one page at time. correctly.

Comment: I need to show 2 pages. like 2 pages in real book - https://previews.123rf.com/images/victoroancea/victoroancea1007/victoroancea100700013/7292811-front-view-of-open-book-on-white-background.jpg

Comment: @111 I have edited code and answer with working code. Check now and let me know.

Comment: If I use this line `//contentVC.imageName.image = self.images[index]` pageViewController not appears. But when I use `contentVC.imageName = images[index]` Your code works. But when I start flipping, my page haven't image in back side of page. When I finish flipping my page image appears.

Comment: @111 Check i have uploaded full project. link: https://github.com/pranavansp/Double-Sided-Page-UIPageViewController-Swift

Comment: It works! But I want to my pages did not completely occupy the whole screen. Because I need to create buttons in different part of controller. Could you tell me how to change size of my flipping pages? Also I can ask new question.